# How to modify shop page main query in WooCommerce to show a variation of every product in the list?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing a shoes shop in WooCommerce. Every shoe has a different color and size. I've added colors and sizes as attributes and then added some products as variable products.

I would like to list in the shop page all products, including **only** colors variations (not sizes!)... Example:

- Variable product A has yellow and black colors and has sizes form 36 to 40
- Variable product B has wine and white colors and has sizes from 36 to 40

Then, my shop page should have four items:

- Product A Yellow
- Product A Black
- Product B Wine
- Product B White

The first step: I'm trying to target shop page main query to modify it and I can't! I'm doing like this:

```
function custom_pre_get_posts( $query ){
    // attempt #1
    if( ( 'product' == get_post_type() || is_post_type_archive('product') ) ):
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );
        return;
    endif;

    // attempt #2
    if( is_shop() ):
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', '1' );
        return;
    endif;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'custom_pre_get_posts');
```

**What am I doing wrong?** Thanks in advance!

The second step: I will try to modify main query to target only the variations I've mentioned before... I do not have idea how to do that too... Any hints?

Thanks!!

Comment: Other have tried that before without success: Product variations are not displayable as other products in shop and archives pages… So if you need to display those, you will have to split your related variable products by colors…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, what do you mean when you say "split your related variable products by color"? Create separated products like so "A Yellow", "A Black", "B Wine" and "B White"? And apply to each product only the size variation? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Yes exactly, create separated products like so "A Yellow", "A Black", "B Wine" and "B White"

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me

```
// ALTERAR A QUERY PRINCIPAL
function fwp_archive_per_page( $query ) {
    if ( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) || is_post_type_archive('product') ) {
        
        $query->set( 'showposts', 16 );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 16 );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                                      'relation'    => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'key'   => 'condicoes_de_exibicao',
                                        'value'     => array('Não exibir no site', 'Não exibir em lugar nenhum'),
                                        'compare'   => 'NOT IN',
                                      )
                                    ) );

    }
}
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'fwp_archive_per_page' );
```